# Would it be good to have a readonly modifier for method level variables?

Tags: language-design

In C# you can use the readonly modifier for a class level field to indicate (to comipler and other DEVS) that once set it cannot be changed.

I'd quite like for the ability to mark a variable declared in a method to be readonly, so once set it cannot be changed.

Is there a way to do this? If not would be a good feature of C# or does it indicate that I my code is poorly constructed if I am wanting it?

Example:

```
public void DoSomthingGreat(string username) 
{
    readonly bool isAdmin = GetTheIsAdminStateforUser(username);

    // do some stuff
    // now ask if the user is admin before doing something else,
    // knowing that the flag shouldn't have been changed by another DEV!
    if (isAdmin)
    {
        // Do some other stuff that only admins can do
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1327544)? - There is no way to do this. If its a good feature or not is the realm of great debate (and that doesn't fit the Q&A format well).

Comment: RE: Q&A format, you are probably right!

Answer (score 1):

Java has this in the form of "final" modifier which can be used also on local variables. 
It is definitely much less useful than final/readonly class-level fields, but whether it is useful at all is a matter of debate and personal style/preference.

On one hand, it can be used to guard against accidental assignments/typos, especially in more complicated methods (which should be arguably broken up/simplified anyway), on the other hand it brings a visual clutter to the source code. It would be much better if variables were readonly by default and you had to use modifier to enable its mutability.

One good use is to add final to local variables in complex/spaghetti code as the first step to reason about, understand and refactor bad code - it's not very invasive and it still provides some useful invariants about the code. In the well-designed code composed of short methods, benefits are smaller because you should be able to see what's going on on the first sight ...

From what I've seen, majority of Java code doesn't use final for local variables. Some major projects (e.g. Apache Http Client) use it though ...

Comment: I use `final` in Java everywhere I can, and have introduced this style to my team. It greatly helps in understanding code. Often, while introducing `final` to local variables, I discover unintented/error-prone reassignments of the variable. In turn, correcting this often tends to refactoring the whole mess. I also introduced using `final` in all method arguments, no exceptions allowed.

Comment: (Cont'd) It doesn't add much visual clutter and it helps add clarity to the *intent* of the code. It's very similar to Scala's `val`, which is mandatory (unless using `var`, of course).

Comment: I now wish the final feature for local variables and method arguments was in C# even more.